# How can I draw table in J2ME Canvas?

Tags: canvas, java-me

I am currently working on a mobile widget I want to draw a table. I also want to select items from table? Can anyone show me sample code to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for draw the table in canvas. You can draw the table like `Graphics.drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)`. And See this article also, [J2ME Table component with focus and scroll.](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/04/22/j2me-table-component-with-focus-and-scroll/) It will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend to use [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) instead

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                
    graphics.setColor(0x00D0D0D0);                    

    graphics.drawRect(0, i * rowh, roww, i * rowh);

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {                    
        graphics.drawRect(j * columnw, i * columnheight, 1 * columnw, 1 * columnheight);    

        rows=30,cols=3,rowh=15,columnw=200,columnheight=15,roww=600.
```